# Parameter as function name

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters

I am not sure if this is possible. I would like to pass in a function name as parameter like this

```
loadContent("http://test.com/", specialFunction);
```

`specialFucntion` is just a string :

```
function loadContent(href, functionIWant){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: href,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(res, textStatus, xhr) {
            helper();
            functionIWant + "()"; //So this would be treated as function
                                  //and it actually calls specialFunction()
                                  //is it possible for this?
        }
    });
}
```

How do I achieve this?

**ADD-ON**

Let's say, I would pass in an array of function names, how do I call it?

```
for(var i = 0; i < functionIWant.length; i++){
   functionIWant[i]; // how? appeciate a lot :)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do it with `functionIWant()`

Example using your provided snippet:

```
function loadContent(href, functionIWant)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: href,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(res, textStatus, xhr) {
            helper();
            functionIWant();
        }
    });
}
```

**For your addendum**

Assuming the following three functions you want to call

```
function foo() {alert("Foo")}
function bar() {alert("bar")}
function baz() {alert("baz")}
```

The best I can recommend if you're passed an array of function names as strings is to follow the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359910/318025).  Basically, you could just do it like this:

```
// Assuming FunctionIWant is an array of strings that represent function names
FunctionIWant = ["foo","bar","baz"];

...

for(var i=0;i<FunctionIWant.length;i++)
    window[FunctionIWant[i]]();
```

If, however, FunctionIWant is an array of actual functions, for example, you can simply iterate over them and call them individually like so:

```
FunctionIWant = [foo,bar,baz] // note, these are not strings

for(var i=0;i<FunctionIWant.length;i++)
    FunctionIWant[i]();
```

In most cases, you'll be better off assigning the function rather than as a string

Comment: chops, question updated. thanks for this straightforward answer :)

Comment: Glad that helped a little. I've updated my answer to accommodate your addendum.

Comment: @chops - Why not just pass an array of actual functions? e.g. `loadContent('path/to...', [function1, function2])`. Then you can just call the functions directly.

Comment: No doubt. I was assuming he was passing the function names as strings (for the addendum, anyway) since he used the term "an array of function names", rather than "an array of functions". I'll modify my answer to extend this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to try to call the function represented by a parameter, simply call it as if that were the name of the function:

```
function loadContent(href, callback)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: href,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(res, textStatus, xhr) {
            helper();
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that `functionIWant` is a string, not a reference to a function [You should make that clear when asking the question]

If that is the case, you want

```
window[functionIWant]();
```

That will work if the function is in the global scope. It would be better that you pass in the reference to the function or if you namespaced your functions.

```
var myFuncs = {
    foo : function(){ alert("asdf"); },
    bar : function(){ alert("qwerty"); }
};

var functionIWant = "foo";
myFuncs[functionIWant]();
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out i didn't make it clear it is a reference or string. :) i haven't try your solution. i'll try later :)

Answer (score 0):

for example you have two functions,

```
var function1 = function( value ) {
  console.log( "foo: " + value );
};

var function2 = function( value ){
  console.log( "bar: " + value );
};
```

and in functionIWant array you have name of function,

```
function loadContent(href, functionIWant)
{
   $.ajax({

    type: "GET",
    url: href,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(res, textStatus, xhr) {
    helper();

    var callbacks = $.Callbacks();

    for(var i = 0; i < functionIWant.length; i++){
     callbacks.add( functionIWant[i] ); //on i=0 add function1
     callbacks.fire( "hello" );          // will fire function1
    }



      }
   });
  }
```